Plymouth Screen Freezes After Installing JetBrains Toolbox on Ubuntu 24.04
I'm having an issue where my Plymouth screen freezes (I hope I'm using the right term). Attached is a screenshot of the problem (https://photos.app.goo.gl/te1yDE1TqPhNeNa5A). This has happened to me three times now. It always occurs after installing JetBrains Toolbox, but this might be a coincidence. I suspect the issue might be related to my graphics card drivers. I have a Lenovo Thinkpad P52 with an Nvidia Quadro P1000.
You can find the system log here: https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1Nk8JsHeb_V0DKqsNMwrGg9k32uqbwdYk. The log is from the time when the issue occurred, and there is also a hardware check from Lenovo Diagnostic Tool for Windows.
The problem manifests as a frozen lock screen. After a hard shutdown, it freezes on the Plymouth screen. I have a dual boot setup, and Windows 11 works fine.
I am using Ubuntu 24.04 with GNOME.
Thanks for any help or suggestions!
